# Pytest unable to use fixture in monkeypatch

Tags: python, pytest

I am trying to use a fixture to monkeypatch a function in a class that I am testing, but keep getting `Fixture "get_staticdata_path" called directly. Fixtures are not meant to be called directly, but are created automatically when test functions request them as parameters`. I am aware that there are similar questions but none of them work for me.

`conftest.py`

```py
import pytest
from pathlib import Path
import spacy


@pytest.fixture
def get_staticdata_path():
    static_data_path = (
        Path(
            __file__,
        )
        .resolve()
        .parent
        / ".."
        / ".."
        / "staticdata"
    )
    return static_data_path


@pytest.fixture
def load_spacy_model():
    def _load_spacy_model():
        static_data_path = get_staticdata_path()
        model_path = static_data_path / "en_core_web_sm"
        nlp = spacy.load(model_path)
        return nlp

    yield _load_spacy_model
```

`tests/natural_language_processing/test_utils.py`

```py
import pytest
from omdenalore.natural_language_processing.utils import TextUtils


@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "text,expected,exception",
    [
        # No inputs
        (None, None, Exception),
        (
            "This is a sample sentence, showing off the stop words filtration.",
            "This sample sentence, showing stop words filtration.",
            None,
        ),
    ],
)
def test_stop_word_removal(text, expected, exception, monkeypatch, load_spacy_model):

    monkeypatch.setattr(
        TextUtils,
        "_load_spacy_model",
        load_spacy_model,
    )

    if exception:
        with pytest.raises(exception):
            _ = TextUtils.stop_word_removal(input_text=text)
    else:
        result = TextUtils.stop_word_removal(input_text=text)
        assert result == expected
```

This is the class `TextUtils` that I am trying to test. Within `stop_word_removal` I am trying to monkeypatch the method `_load_spacy_model` which is used to get a spacy model with the fixture `load_spacy_model`.

```py
class TextUtils:
    """Utility functions for handling text data"""

    @staticmethod
    def _load_spacy_model():
        nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
        return nlp

    @staticmethod
    def stop_word_removal(
        input_text: Union[List[str], str],
    ) -> Union[
        List[str], str,
    ]:
        """
        Remove noise from the input text.
        This function can be use to remove common english
        words like "is, a , the".

        :param input_text: Input text to remove stop words from
        :type input_text: str or List[str]
        :returns: Clean text with no noise

        :Example:

        from omdenalore.natural_language_processing.utils import
        TextUtils
        >>> input = "Hello, the chicken crossed the street"
        >>> TextUtils.stop_word_removal(input)
        "Hello, chicken crossed the street"
        """
        nlp = TextUtils._load_spacy_model()
        if isinstance(input_text, list):
            processed_input = []
            for sentence in input_text:
                if isinstance(sentence, str):
                    doc = nlp(sentence)
                    processed_input.append(
                        " ".join([token.text for token in doc if not token.is_stop])
                    )
            return processed_input
        elif isinstance(input_text, str):
            doc = nlp(input_text)
            return " ".join([token.text for token in doc if not token.is_stop])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `get_staticdata_path` fixture directly in another fixture: `load_spacy_model`.

Have you tried passing it as a fixture?

Example:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def load_spacy_model(get_staticdata_path):
    def _load_spacy_model():
        static_data_path = get_staticdata_path
        model_path = static_data_path / "en_core_web_sm"
        nlp = spacy.load(model_path)
        return nlp

    yield _load_spacy_model
```

Look at this example in the docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#back-to-fixtures

Comment: Thanks yes that was the issue, didn't realize that I can't use the fixture as a standard function.

Comment: @yudhiesh You're welcome! I'm glad you solved it.